# Force alignment fault in arm assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi2

I'm doing bare metal development on a raspberry pi 2 (cortex-a7) and I'd like to test exception handlers.

To test the data abort exception handler, I'm trying to cause an alignment fault. I tried

```
ldr             r0, #1
```

but gcc is complaining with: Error : internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up.

How can i provoke an alignment fault on my platform?
Thank you.

Comment: For example, `ldr r0, [pc, #1]`

Comment: you are saying load into r0 the thing at address #1 which is/may be too far away.  jester has a simple example of something that would work or perhaps what you wanted to do is ldr r1,=1; ldr r0,[r1]

Comment: also need to make sure that you have configured the processor to fault on unaligned transfers.

Comment: I have caused an abort by deferencing a pointer to type bool from <stdbool.h>